# VBS variable use to execute

Tags: variables, vbscript, execution

Here's my vbs :

```
Myvar = "calc"
command = "powershell.exe -nologo -command Myvar"
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run command,0
```

It does not work. calc is not executed.

Later, i will substitue calc by a ps1 file with spaces.
Can you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"... Myvar"` is just a quoted string, there is no substitution of the variable's value.

You need to *concatenate* the variable, to append the value from the variable, using the concatenation operator `&`:

```
command = "powershell.exe -nologo -command " & Myvar
```